# Issue with reading from txt using csV

Tags: python, json, csv, text, file-handling

I'm working with project and I'm stuck because when I tried to read from file nrwolek,nrwolbiz,nrwolpr instead of getting [1E, 2E, 3E, 4E, 5E], [1B,2B,3B,4B,5B], [1P, 2P, 3P] I got nrwolek = 1E, nrwolbiz = 2E, nrwolpr u 3E. It seams that it doesn't read a whole list but only elements from it. Is it a method to correct this? Or is a good solution to solve this with json? Code -reading :

```
import csv
from lot import DatabaseofLoty, Lot

def read_from_csv(path):
    loty = []
    with open(path,"r") as file_handle:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_handle)
        for row in reader:
            numer_lotu = row["numer_lotu"]
            id_samolotu = row["id_samolotu"]
            czas_lotu = row['czas_lotu']
            trasa = row['trasa']
            wolne_miejscaek = row['wolne_miejscaek']
            wolne_miejscabiz = row['wolne_miejscabiz']
            wolne_miejscapr = row['wolne_miejscapr']
            bramka = row['bramka']
            cenaek = row['cenaek']
            cenabiz = row['cenabiz']
            cenapr = row['cenapr']
            nrwolek = row['nrwolek']
            nrwolbiz = row['nrwolbiz']
            nrwolpr = row['nrwolpr']
            lot = Lot(numer_lotu, id_samolotu, czas_lotu, trasa,
                      wolne_miejscaek,
                      wolne_miejscabiz, wolne_miejscapr, bramka,
                      cenaek, cenabiz, cenapr)
            loty.append(lot)
            database = DatabaseofLoty(loty)
    return database
print(read_from_csv("loty.txt"))
```

Text file:

```
numer_lotu,id_samolotu,czas_lotu,trasa,wolne_miejscaek,wolne_miejscabiz,wolne_miejscapr,bramka,cenaek,cenabiz,cenapr,nrwolek,nrwolbiz,nrwolpr
1,3,3:52,Amsterdam-Berlin,129,92,192,8,52,68,75, [1E, 2E, 3E, 4E, 5E], [1B,2B,3B,4B,5B], [1P, 2P, 3P]
2,3,3:52,Tokio-Berlin,129,92,192,8,580,720,1234
```

Comment: It happens because you have broken CSV file. You need to quote values which contains delimiter `"[1E, 2E, 3E, 4E, 5E]"`.

Comment: Your "lists" in your CSV file should be quoted (or the commas escaped), if you want to read them as a single field.

Comment: You have a (badly formatted) CSV file; but unless you have control over how that file is written, there is no good way to read that as JSON.

Comment: If you do want to read the list as a list into Python, then JSON could be a better format; but that depends on whether you can rewrite your input file.

Comment: Quotting doesn't work , I got the same output but the nrwolek has quote

Comment: @Paul, seems like there's problem with your quotation. Could you add new file version?

Comment: I solved this now, because I used a delimiter and list doesn't contains ",". Now I use - instead of it in list :)

Comment: @Paul, or you may just quote value properly